# How to remove splitter and keeping one ui element

Tags: layout, foobar2000

Since foobar2000's splitter UI elements are containers providing space for two adjacent ui elements, when removing the splitter, both adjacent elements are removed, too. But often, when reordering a layout I want to keep one of the two. I could "cut" the one to keep, if it was possible to just "remove" the splitter. Unfortunately, "cut" is the only removal operation, so the backuped ui element is overwritten when "cut"ting the splitter.

So there's no obvious way to remove a splitter while keeping one of the two adjacent ui elements, is there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've got an approach to this which is similar to yours, but simpler.

1. Enable Layout editing mode
2. Right click the element you want to keep and select 'Copy'
3. Point the splitter separator (a double-pointed arrow should appear) and right click it (so that after you right click, both halves are highlighted; if only one gets highlighted, try right-clicking again) - you are selecting the whole splitter element this way - and select 'Paste'
4. Disable Layout editing mode

This is the simplest method I've found. The absence of a native way to remove one half of the splitter is really puzzling, but that's it.

Comment: Seems logical and obvious...after reading it. So it must be the right solution. ;-)

Comment: It's remarkably difficult to click to the right point.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I am using now is inconvenient but simple enough:

Prerequisite: Somewhere I always have a tabbed ui element.

1. Enter layout editing mode
2. Select the "tabs" ui element
3. Right click and "add new tab"
4. Select the ui element you want to keep, right click, and "cut ui element"
5. Select the new tab, right click "paste ui element"
6. remove the splitter, effectively removing the splitter and the two adjacent elements (one of them already empty)
7. in the now empty space restore your element by selecting/cutting the backed up element in the tab
8. right click the tab and click "remove tab"

Answer (score -3):

in layout editting mode: right click on the splitter itself and select "cut"

Comment: This is, essentially, what the accepted answer already is. However, the accepted answer contains a lot more helpful information.